# Vehicle Category, Make & Model query

Tags: html, css

I have a custom database table where I am storing an ID, CATEGORY, MAKE and MODEL.

```
id    category       make                   model
---   --------      ------                  -------
1     heavy truck   fontaine modification   m2 autohauler
2     heavy truck   fontaine modification   volvo autohauler
3     kit car       porsche                 porshe 904
4     kit car       rossion                 Q1
5     kit car       rossion                 Q1R
```

Link to SQL Test data: https://sqltest.net/#246173

I am querying this table in the database with the following and attempting to remove duplicate categories and makes from the output:

```
<?php
$query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table_name");
$category = '';
$make = '';
foreach($query as $mm) :
    if($mm->category != $category):
         echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
         echo '<div class="category"><strong>'.$mm->category.'</strong></div>';
        $category = $mm->category;
    endif;

    if($mm->make != $make):
        echo '<div class="make '.$mm->make.'">'.$mm->make.'</div>';
        $make = $mm->make;
    endif;
    if($mm->model):
        echo '<div class="model">'.$mm->model.'</div>';
    endif;

endforeach;
?>
```

This will output something like this:

**HEAVY TRUCK**

***FONTAINE MODIFICATION***

M2 AUTOHAULER

VOLVO AUTOHAULER

**KIT CAR**

***PORSCHE***

PORSCHE 904

***ROSSION***

Q1R

Q1

I can get it all listed out with the makes under the right Categories and the Models under the right Makes. However, I want to have them laid out differently. I want to be able to wrap the makes and models in a 3 column layout with the models hidden under each make until it is clicked.

But, when I try to wrap them in a floating column div, it all gets messed up within the foreach loop of course. I need a better way to query and output this data.

**This is what it currently looks like:**
[image]

**Here is a screenshot of what I want to get it to:**
[image]

**Here is the example code of what I want it to get to:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $(".make").click(function() {
   $(this).next('.model').toggle();
 });
});
```

```css
.make-model:after {
 clear: both;
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.make-model .category {
 background: #68bac9;
 color:#FFF;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding-left: 7px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.make-model .make {
 color: #026e81;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.make-model .make:after {
 font-family: "FontAwesome";
 content: "\00a0\f0d7";
 color: #8ccdd9;
}
.make-model .model {
  list-style:none;
 color: #026e81;
 font-weight: 400;
 display: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.d-1of4 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  width: 25%;
}
.clearfix {
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="make-model">
<div class="category">
 <strong>HEAVY TRUCK</strong>
</div>
<div class="d-1of4">
 <div class="make">FONTAINE MODIFICATION</div>
 <ul class="model">
  <li>M2 AUTOHAULER</li>
  <li>VOLVO AUTOHAULER</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="category">
 <strong>KIT CAR</strong>
</div>
<div class="d-1of4">
 <div class="make">PORSCHE</div>
 <ul class="model">
  <li>PORSCHE 904</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="d-1of4">
 <div class="make">ROSSION</div>
 <ul class="model">
  <li>Q1</li>
  <li>Q1R</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="d-1of4">
 <div class="make">S-1 ROADSTER</div>
 <ul class="model">
  <li>S-1 ROADSTER</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearifx"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a table?

Comment: You should also provide a layout example of what you want. Suggestion: create it with html and post it here.

Comment: @dakis - I added a screenshot of what I want it to end up like. The models in columns with the makes underneath them in an unordered list that will be hidden until the make is clicked on. I have that part working and ready to go, I just need to figure out how to lay them out in the column order.

Comment: Why this isn't marked with php tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being late with an answer.

#### METHOD 1:

This is the elegant solution. The trick is to copy the initial fetched data (`$vehicles`) into another array (`$groupedVehicles`) in a "grouped" way. This grouped list will then be iterated and, based on its structure, the HTML code will be built.

**Initial data (`$vehicles`):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category] => HEAVY TRUCK
            [make] => FONTAINE MODIFICATION
            [model] => M2 AUTOHAULER
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category] => HEAVY TRUCK
            [make] => FONTAINE MODIFICATION
            [model] => VOLVO AUTOHAULER
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => FERRARI
            [model] => 488 GTB
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => FERRARI
            [model] => 488 SPIDER
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => PORSCHE
            [model] => PORSCHE 904
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => ROSSION
            [model] => Q1
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => ROSSION
            [model] => Q1R
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => S-1 ROADSTER
            [model] => S-1 ROADSTER
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => STERLING SPORTS CARS
            [model] => CIMBRIA
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => STERLING SPORTS CARS
            [model] => FORTVAC
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => STERLING SPORTS CARS
            [model] => STERLING
            [part_number] => 
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [category] => KIT CAR
            [make] => STERLING SPORTS CARS
            [model] => VIPER 2000
            [part_number] => 
        )

)
```

**Grouped data (`$groupedVehicles`):**

```
Array
(
    [HEAVY TRUCK] => Array
        (
            [FONTAINE MODIFICATION] => Array
                (
                    [0] => M2 AUTOHAULER
                    [1] => VOLVO AUTOHAULER
                )

        )

    [KIT CAR] => Array
        (
            [FERRARI] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 488 GTB
                    [1] => 488 SPIDER
                )

            [PORSCHE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PORSCHE 904
                )

            [ROSSION] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Q1
                    [1] => Q1R
                )

            [S-1 ROADSTER] => Array
                (
                    [0] => S-1 ROADSTER
                )

            [STERLING SPORTS CARS] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CIMBRIA
                    [1] => FORTVAC
                    [2] => STERLING
                    [3] => VIPER 2000
                )

        )

)
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you must duplicate the whole data list.

Here are my files. You can test them as they are. I slightly changed your naming conventions. Though not the table structures. In the table `wp_make_model` I added two new records, in order to test the display of more than four `make`s per `category`. Search for "@todo" and act accordingly. I used the PDO extension to connect to database and build an object per each db record. E.g. to simulate your function `get_results`.

**vehicles.php:**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM wp_make_model
        ORDER BY
            category ASC,
            make ASC,
            model ASC
        ';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$vehicles = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

/*
 * Just for test-printing the data.
 * @todo Uncomment, see the results, delete.
 */
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($vehicles, TRUE) . '</pre>';
// Holds the list of vehicles grouped by category, make, model - in this order.
$groupedVehicles = [];

foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    if (!array_key_exists($vehicle->category, $groupedVehicles)) {
        $groupedVehicles[$vehicle->category] = [];
    }

    if (!array_key_exists($vehicle->make, $groupedVehicles[$vehicle->category])) {
        $groupedVehicles[$vehicle->category][$vehicle->make] = [];
    }

    $groupedVehicles[$vehicle->category][$vehicle->make][] = $vehicle->model;
}

/*
 * Just for test-printing the data.
 * @todo Uncomment, see the results, delete.
 */
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($groupedVehicles, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Vehicles</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="vehicles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JS resources -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vehicles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>
            Demo vehicles
        </h1>

        <div class="vehicles">
            <?php
            foreach ($groupedVehicles as $category => $makes) {
                $makesPerRow = 0;
                ?>
                <div class="category">
                    <?php echo $category; ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                foreach ($makes as $make => $models) {
                    $makesPerRow++;
                    ?>
                    <div class="d-1of4">
                        <div class="make">
                            <?php echo $make; ?>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="model">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($models as $model) {
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php echo $model; ?>
                                </li>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    if ($makesPerRow % 4 === 0) {
                        $makesPerRow = 0;
                        ?>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }

                if ($makesPerRow > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**connection.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a PDO connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

// Error reporting.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER! */

// Create a PDO instance as db connection to db.
$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

**vehicles.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".make").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.model').toggle();
    });
});
```

**vehicles.css:**

```
/***************************************/
/* Base settings */
/***************************************/

html {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/***************************************/
/* Fonts */
/***************************************/

html, body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

/***************************************/
/* Layout settings */
/***************************************/

.vehicles:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.vehicles .category {
    background: #68bac9;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.vehicles .make {
    color: #026e81;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vehicles .make:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\00a0\f0d7";
    color: #8ccdd9;
}
.vehicles .model {
    list-style:none;
    color: #026e81;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.d-1of4 {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
    width: 25%;
}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

#### METHOD 2:

It has the advantage that the initial data doesn't need to be duplicated. Though is hard to follow and it definitely requires that the data is properly sorted. For this method only the `vehicles2.php` is relevant. The rest of the files are the same.

**vehicles2.php**

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM wp_make_model
        ORDER BY
            category ASC,
            make ASC,
            model ASC
        ';

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$query = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

/*
 * Just for test-printing the data.
 * @todo Uncomment, see the results, delete.
 */
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($vehicles, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Vehicles</title>

        <!-- CSS resources -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="vehicles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JS resources -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vehicles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>
            Demo vehicles
        </h1>

        <div class="vehicles">
            <?php
            $category = '';
            $make = '';
            $result = '';

            foreach ($query as $mm) {
                if ($mm->category !== $category) { // Current category is different than the previous one.
                    // End of previous category row (if any).
                    if ($category !== '') {
                        // Close the previous make container.
                        $result .= '</ul>';
                        $result .= '</div>';

                        // Clearfix if not already done after the last make container in previous category.
                        if ($makesPerRow > 0) {
                            $result .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
                        }
                    }

                    // Initialize for the current, newly created category.
                    $makesPerRow = 0;

                    // Define current category container.
                    $result .= '<div class="category">' . $mm->category . '</div>';
                    $category = $mm->category;

                    $makesPerRow++;

                    // Define the container of the first make.
                    $result .= '<div class="d-1of4">';
                    $result .= '<div class="make">' . $mm->make . '</div>';
                    $result .= '<ul class="model">';
                    $make = $mm->make;
                } else { // Current category is the same with the previous one.
                    if ($mm->make !== $make) { // The current make is different than the previous one.
                        // So, close the previous make container.
                        $result .= '</ul>';
                        $result .= '</div>';

                        // Clearfix if the 4th (or 8th, etc) make container was just closed.
                        if ($makesPerRow % 4 === 0) {
                            $makesPerRow = 0;
                            $result .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
                        }

                        $makesPerRow++;

                        // Define the container of the current make.
                        $result .= '<div class="d-1of4">';
                        $result .= '<div class="make">' . $mm->make . '</div>';
                        $result .= '<ul class="model">';
                        $make = $mm->make;
                    }
                }

                // Always executed in each iteration step.
                if ($mm->model) {
                    $result .= '<li>' . $mm->model . '</li>';
                }
            }

            echo $result;
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Create & fill the db table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_make_model` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `part_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `wp_make_model` (`category`, `make`, `model`, `part_number`)
VALUES
    ('HEAVY TRUCK', 'FONTAINE MODIFICATION', 'M2 AUTOHAULER', ''),
    ('HEAVY TRUCK', 'FONTAINE MODIFICATION', 'VOLVO AUTOHAULER', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'PORSCHE', 'PORSCHE 904', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'ROSSION', 'Q1', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'ROSSION', 'Q1R', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'S-1 ROADSTER', 'S-1 ROADSTER', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'STERLING SPORTS CARS', 'CIMBRIA', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'STERLING SPORTS CARS', 'FORTVAC', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'STERLING SPORTS CARS', 'STERLING', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'STERLING SPORTS CARS', 'VIPER 2000', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'FERRARI', '488 GTB', ''),
    ('KIT CAR', 'FERRARI', '488 SPIDER', '')
;
```

Comment: @TylerRobinson You are welcome. I changed the answer's text. I also changed the code in "vehicles.php" and "vehicles.css", and I added a new file named "vehicles2.php" representing a second method, e.g. based on what you've tried. Have fun and good luck.